# Incrementing Arrays in JS

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a list of messages with the latest at the top. This is in Node red. I have a 4 line LCD I wish to display Pager messages on

To me this should work but it doesn't, Just shows the message in the last line and won't add new ones

```
var message = [];

message.splice(4,0,msg.message);
message.splice(0,1);

msg.payload1 = message[0];
msg.payload2 = message[1];
msg.payload3 = message[2];
msg.payload4 = message[3];
return msg;
```

Here is the Node red flow

```
[{"id":"dd82941d.5b65c8","type":"function","z":"4cce1974.6fb398","name":"Format Pager Message","func":"var str = msg.payload;\nvar pager = str.substring(9,16);\nvar length = str.length - 2;\nvar message = str.substring(17,length);\nmsg.pager = pager;\nmsg.message = message;\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":311,"y":195,"wires":[["2b7dc9b1.c01356"]]},{"id":"188de5a3.ba258a","type":"rpi-lcd","z":"4cce1974.6fb398","name":"","pins":"12,7,8,25,24,23","x":1113,"y":195,"wires":[]},{"id":"f66dd00d.9b67e","type":"template","z":"4cce1974.6fb398","name":"","field":"payload","fieldType":"msg","format":"handlebars","syntax":"mustache","template":"1:{{payload1}}\n2:{{payload2}}\n3:{{payload3}}\n4:{{payload4}}","x":942,"y":193,"wires":[["188de5a3.ba258a"]]},{"id":"d6971b25.349b38","type":"debug","z":"4cce1974.6fb398","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"true","x":717,"y":245,"wires":[]},{"id":"7ee7f56e.176e5c","type":"inject","z":"4cce1974.6fb398","name":"","topic":"test","payload":"0123456789abcdefgHello Worldyz","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":115,"y":229,"wires":[["dd82941d.5b65c8"]]},{"id":"2b7dc9b1.c01356","type":"function","z":"4cce1974.6fb398","name":"Stack Messages","func":"var message = [];\n\nmessage.splice(4,0,msg.message);\nmessage.splice(0,1);\n\nmsg.payload1 = message[0];\nmsg.payload2 = message[1];\nmsg.payload3 = message[2];\nmsg.payload4 = message[3];\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":539,"y":194,"wires":[["f66dd00d.9b67e","d6971b25.349b38"]]}]
```

Comment: What's the question/issue?

Comment: Yeah OP, what's your actual question?  Is your current code throwing exceptions?  A wee bit more info please :)

Comment: It dosent work!

Comment: @JamesBlackwell We still don't know what doesn't work. You have not specified any additional information required for us to determine what wrong. We should not be debugging your code for you.

Comment: sorry very new to this! im i along the right lines for incrimenting an array?

Comment: You are in a way but just use `.push` function to add to an array.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to add items to the front of the array. Don't mess about with splicing it.

```
message.unshift(msg)
```

Use [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) to remove the last element from the array.

```
while (message.length > 4) {
    message.pop();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunatly that only changes the first one but dosent push the next one down :(

Comment: @JamesBlackwell — It does push the next one down. http://jsbin.com/gerenojaki/1/edit?js,console

Comment: come on @JamesBlackwell, look at that guy's score :p how can you say it does not do what he says :)

Comment: I have been known to make mistakes, but if you're going to say it doesn't work, then provide an [mcve]

Comment: must be a node red thing then as i cant get it working

Comment: var message = [1,2,3,4];

    message.unshift(msg.message)
    while (message.length > 4) {
        message.pop();
    }

msg.payload1 = message[0];
msg.payload2 = message[1];
msg.payload3 = message[2];
msg.payload4 = message[3];
return msg;

Comment: @JamesBlackwell — [That throws an error](http://jsbin.com/rarelimugi/edit?js,console). It is not an [mcve] that shows the problem you describe.

Comment: doesnt throw an error for me just doesnt work! are you using Node Red?

Comment: @JamesBlackwell — There is nothing in that code example which using Node Red would make a difference for. You forgot the `;` before `while`. This possibly didn't matter if your test because you likely had a new line there and triggered ASI. If I fix that, then it errors because there is an illegal return statement. If I fix that, by replacing it with a console.log, then it errors because `msg` is undefined. You need to create a [mcve].

Comment: Finally figured it out, I needed to use global variables

Answer (score -1):

Solved using global variables

```
//Check array.length less than 3 (4 items only in array, pops last item)
if(context.global.array.length < 4){
    context.global.array.push(msg.payload);
}else{
    context.global.array.push(msg.payload);
    context.global.array.shift();
}

msg.payload = context.global.array.toString();
msg.payload1 = context.global.array[3];
msg.payload2 = context.global.array[2];
msg.payload3 = context.global.array[1];
msg.payload4 = context.global.array[0];
return msg;
```